# QT message box not popus on button click

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I just started learning QT and what i wanted to accomplish is to get popup message on buttons click.
Here is how my file looks like:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow *mainWindow = new MainWindow();


    QLabel *text = new QLabel("Some text");
    QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("Click");

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;

    layout->addWidget(btn);
    layout->addWidget(text);

    QObject::connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), &app, SLOT(popup()));

    mainWindow->setLayout(layout);
    mainWindow->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::popUp()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "New Box", "Message");
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMessageBox>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();


private slots:
    void popUp();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Can you please explain what i've done wrong or  maybe there is something missing in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that the graphical part implement it inside the class `MainWindow` since the member `ui` that is private handles the design.

```
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QLabel *text = new QLabel("Some text");
    QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("Click");

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;

    layout->addWidget(btn);
    layout->addWidget(text);

    ui->centralWidget->setLayout(layout);

    connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::popUp);
}
```

Do not make any changes to `main.cpp`, the code should look like this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: what is centralWidget?? i'm getting error with this widget:  mainwindow.cpp:19: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QLayout'
     ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(btn);
                                ^

Comment: @thank you it worked! Can you please explain why in this line connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::popUp);  we must use &QPushButton::clicked and &MainWindow::popUp, instead of connect(btn,SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(popUp()));

Comment: That is the new syntax that is recommended to use, for more information you can read: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax , if my answer helps you please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong connection. You should connect the `clicked()` signal to the `mainWindow`'s slot `popUp()`, because it is a member of the `MainWindow` class. And don't forget about case sensitivity of c++ (pop**Up**, not popup):

```
QObject::connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), mainWindow, SLOT(popUp()));
```

Comment: The case sensitivity issue wouldn't be a problem when using the [new signal slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) since a compiler error would have been thrown.

Comment: @Vladimir Bershov i made changes, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You're connecting to a private slot from outside mainwindow.
The application output probably shows you a warning like this:

> QObject::connect: No such slot QApplication::popup()

Usually what you'd want to do is put stuff used inside mainwindow, inside mainwindow class.

Eg: Create the layout inside the constructor.
You can use the parent argument when creating the objects to get them destroyed when you're done with mainwindow.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QLabel *text = new QLabel("Some text", this);
    QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("Click", this);

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;

    QObject::connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(popUp()));

    ui->centralWidget->setLayout(layout);
    this->show();
}
```

You have to use `ui->centralWidget`, because that's how mainwindow works. The application output should have given you a warning for that as well. 
Like this:

> QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on MainWindow "MainWindow", which already has a layout

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have to work on the file `mainwindow.cpp`. You have already create the slot, so connect it adding this code in MainWindow's constructor (if you don't know witch is the mw constructor it is the function where is written `ui->setupUi(this);`)

```
connect(ui->btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(popUp()));
```

now in the slot `MainWindow::popUp();` put this code:

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText("text to write");
msgBox.exec();
```

remember to include `QMessageBox` **in mainwindow.cpp**, you shouldn't write code on main.cpp, it must be this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWindow w;
        w.show();

        return a.exec();
    }
```

Comment: gives me this error: mainwindow.cpp:11: error: 'class Ui::MainWindow' has no member named 'btn'
     connect(ui->btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(popUp()));
                 ^

Comment: have you created a PushButton graphic object named btn in the graphic view? If not you have to draw it

Comment: you can create it opening the file mainwindow.ui (in Forms)  and here you can draw your objects